# What could cause long build times?

Tags: codenameone

I have a test project containing a lot of lazy loaded Form-derived test modules.
These test modules are all very small - just as big as the corresponding test case.

Now I realized that the build times increase with every new Form-derived test module.

Any idea what would cause such extremely long build times?

[image]

I am talking about a project containing 50 forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build times you are seeing are crazy slow. I don't see a way this would be possible you might be hitting an odd case that sends a build server on a loop.

The times above include 2 factors: Queue & Build.

If queue exceeds 15 minutes on iOS or Windows (3 minutes on other platforms) we get an automatic notification as it assumes something is broken. Queuing happens when you are waiting for a server to process your build, every time a higher grade account sends a build he is placed in the head of the queue regardless of your waiting time so basic/free accounts sometimes hit that 15 minute limit but this is still rare as we have enough servers to serve everyone.

Time like this means one of two things:

- We aren't getting notified of long queue duration
- You found something that is causing very long build times for some reason

Both are very bad please send a build and note how long the "queue" stage lasts (you might need to reload the page as this status doesn't always refresh correctly). If it's the building stage that lasts too long we will need a test case.

Comment: I have only once seen the queue stage indicated in the list.

Comment: Can you create a test case for a build that is very slow? this is something I'd like to inspect, it might be a problem in the optimizer logic.

Comment: It is likely that the extended build time is caused by just one Form class. I'll try to find out which one

Comment: See [#2024 - Extremely long build times on the build server](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2024)

Comment: Thanks, we were able to reproduce this. As a short term workaround you can split the method to smaller methods but we plan on fixing this on the servers as such long builds can cripple our service. This seems to be a "misbehavior" of clang.

Comment: That's good to read. So - big methods are to be avoided in the meantime, did I unterstand that correctly?

Comment: We just posted a fix that should be on the build servers now, I just sent a test build and it took 3 minutes. Thanks!